# Have an error when trying do make a Cypress.Commands.add("login", email: string, password: string

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am working with Cypress dong e2e test, I went to the docs and I want to make a cutom login command for login with best practice behavior

this is my code in support/commands.ts which I grabbed from here https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/cypress-best-practices/:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (email: string, password: string) => {
  cy.request("/auth/login", {
    email,
    password,
  }).then((r) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("token", r.body.token)
  })
})
```

and I have this error popping up:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(email: string, password: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CommandFn"login">'.
```

why am I having this error, can I avoid it?
also, what is the best way in your opinion to make a custom login command? any recipe?

Regards

Comment: Where exactly is this error appearing in your code?

Comment: underlining (email: string, password: string). I did // @ts-ignore but i don t know if it solved the issue because the code is not working in general

Answer (score 0):

went to :

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      login(email: string, password: string): void;
    }
  }
}
```

and deleted the Chainable from login(email: string, password: string): Chainable;
and is not throwing the error